# Bootstrap fill the remaining height

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

so i have using bootstrap grid and having trouble to handle the empty space created when the div don't fill the entire height like this

[image: empty height]

when i have this kind of configuration

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8"> <div>diklat bkcu</div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"> <div>peserta diklat bkcu</div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-8"> <div>grafik perkembangan gerakan</div></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"> <div>tabel perkembangan</div></div>
</div>
```

what i want to get is to be like this
[image: like this]
i can get this by using this layout

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8"> 
        <div>diklat bkcu</div>
        <div>grafik perkembangan gerakan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"> 
        <div>peserta diklat bkcu</div>
        <div>tabel perkembangan</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the question is how do i get this desktop layout (second image) with the mobile layout that look like this???

```
+---------------------------------+
| diklat bkcu                     |
+---------------------------------+
| peserta diklat bkcu             |
+---------------------------------+
| grafik perkembangan gerakan     |
+---------------------------------+
| tabel perkembangan              |
+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: See this:https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Answer (score -1):

you may try to use this

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-8 d-sm-none"> 
        <div>diklat bkcu</div>
        <div>grafik perkembangan gerakan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 d-sm-none"> 
        <div class="row">peserta diklat bkcu</div>
        <div class="row">tabel perkembangan</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 d-none">diklat bkcu</div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 d-none">peserta diklat bkcu  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 d-none">grafik perkembangan gerakan </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 d-none">tabel perkembangan  </div>
</div>
```

You only want the mobile that working this without the space right?

`+---------------------------------+
| diklat bkcu                     |
+---------------------------------+
| grafik perkembangan gerakan     |
+---------------------------------+
| peserta diklat bkcu             |
+---------------------------------+
| tabel perkembangan              |
+---------------------------------+`

Try on this method, if you want to specific on the mobile version.

Comment: hmmm maybe i write it wrong or you read it wrong but what i want is the second mobile view.... with the layout for the desktop of the second image... your solution is pretty much a copy paste from what i mentioned above

Comment: Ok, you want the mobile layout like the second picture that you posted? Is that correct?

Comment: Please check the updated version to see is that what you ask for.

Comment: that is not a very good way in term of performance, since it simply just hide the component at specific screen size and the result is you having duplicate component which is hidden